# message box does not appear after the event afterupdate

Tags: ms-access

Good morning
I try to explain myself
Starting from the highest level to the lowest this is the sequence
The Main Mask is a "Navigationform"
By clicking in the body of the "Navigationform" in the properties window there is the name of another element called "SubformNavigation"
Inside the SubformNavigation there is a subform called "Purchase documents"
Which contains the field that I would like to insert the VBA code to is called “Contract” and its control source is called “Top Contract”
So

1. Form: Navigation mask
2. Form: SubformNavigation
3. Form: Purchase documents
4. Field: Contrac

I wrote this code for the event afterupdate

```
Private Sub Contratto_Afterupdate()
If Forms![Maschera di spostamento].Form!SottomascheraSpostamento!Contratto.Value = "2270100831" Then
    MsgBox "Attenzione Per questo contratto è necessario un aumento del 8,9% del consuntivo.", vbCritical, "Attenzione"
Else
    MsgBox "errore"
End If
End Sub
```

But afterupdate not work

I also tried with the ……“On change” event

I tried inserting a new textbox that takes the value from the "Contratto" field and inserting the Afterupdate event

but it doesn't work

can anyone help me understand?
Thank you all

I hope for an answer that will help me

Comment: Neither message box shows? Have you set a breakpoint and step debugged code to confirm event does not trigger? Try `If Me.Contratto = "2270100831" Then`.

Comment: How did you generate the event procedure? Did you select "Event Procedure" in the event property and click the ellipsis to open VBA editor?